# Can the intmax_t hold size_t?

Tags: c, printf, size-type

Can the intmax_t hold size_t maximum decimal number?
And what size type in printf  have a biggest priority uintmax_t/intmax_t or size_t (ex. if i write printf("%zjd", x))?

Comment: What do you mean by "priority"?

Comment: by priority i'm mean "priority of handling" size-types specificators

Comment: I suspect `%zjd` leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why would you want to write `"%zjd"` in `printf`? Even if it was allowed, it's a contradiction and makes no sense.

Comment: "Can the intmax_t hold size_t maximum decimal number?" if `INTMAX_MAX` >= `SIZE_MAX` witch is probably not the case on an lot of implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Most likely not**

Both are implementation specific, so it's not really possible to answer.

`size_t` is (usually) an unsigned integer holding the largest possible number of bits that will fit in a register on a given CPU. That's not exactly guaranteed in reality though, but I still haven't found an example where this isn't true.

`intmax_t` is a signed integer, meaning it will probably have the bits required to store any value that a `size_t` can hold, but large values will not mean the same; the largest value that a `size_t` can hold, is likely going to be a negative integer when interpreted as an `intmax_t`.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, since `size_t` is unsigned that risks dropping one bit.
2. I don't think you understand how `printf()` works, you can have "an optional length modifier" but not more than one.

Comment: i know it, i'm try to write a copy of printf function, and i'm see that stdio.h-printf have a "size priority handling" if string have more than one size-type mod.

Comment: What about `uintmax_t` then?